# javafx.fxml.LoadException when I try to change scene by selecting an Item

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am creating a bidding system where a scene has the list of items available for auction. when the user clicks on the item, the scene should change to another anchorpane where all the details related to the item will displayed. When I click on the item I get this exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/Deepak95/IdeaProjects/Package2/out/production/Package2/System/view/ItemView.fxml:9
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:928)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
at System.Main.showItem(Main.java:61)
at System.View.ItemOverviewController.lambda$initialize$2(ItemOverviewController.java:23)
at System.View.ItemOverviewController$$Lambda$154/21527645.changed(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase$$Lambda$135/26372034.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:176)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:142)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(TableView.java:2900)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2430)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2360)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:1898)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:215)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:148)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$255/19643353.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/10455932.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: System.View.ItemViewController
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
... 72 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: System.View.ItemViewController.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
... 74 more
```

Here are the functions responsible for the scene change:

```
 public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void showItemOverview(){
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/ItemOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
        ItemOverviewController controller=loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void showItem(Item I){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/ItemView.fxml"));
        AnchorPane itemview= (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(itemview);
        ItemViewController controller=loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this);
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the **overview class** and its corresponding `fxml` file:

```
package System.View;
import System.Main;
import System.Model.Item;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
public class ItemOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Item> itemTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item,String> itemnamecolumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item,Integer> basepricecolumn;
    private Main main;
    public ItemOverviewController(){

    }
    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        itemnamecolumn.setCellValueFactory(celldata->celldata.getValue().itemnameProperty());
        basepricecolumn.setCellValueFactory(celldata->celldata.getValue().initialpriceProperty().asObject());
        itemTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable,oldvalue,newvalue)->main.showItem(newvalue));
    }
    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main=main;
        itemTableView.setItems(main.getItemdata());
    }
}
```

fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"        minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="System.View.ItemOverviewController">
    <children>
    <TableView fx:id="itemTableView" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="itemnamecolumn" prefWidth="310.0" text="Item Name" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="basepricecolumn" prefWidth="289.0" text="BasePrice" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the **itemview controller class** and its fxml file:

```
package System.View;
import System.Model.Item;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import System.Main;
public class ItemViewController {
    Item I;
    @FXML
    Label itemname;
    @FXML
    Label description;
    @FXML
    Label biddername;
    @FXML
    Label baseprice;
    @FXML
    Label currentprice;
    Main main;
    public ItemViewController(Item I){
        this.I=I;
    }
    public void initialize(){
        itemname.setText(I.getItemname());
        description.setText(I.getDescription());
        biddername.setText(I.getBiddername());
        baseprice.setText(I.getInitialprice().toString());
        currentprice.setText(I.getInitialprice().toString());
    }
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```

**fxml** file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="System.View.ItemViewController">
 <children>
  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="46.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <items>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
           <children>
              <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="296.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <items>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                       <children>
                          <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="296.0" layoutX="-22.0" layoutY="-2.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                       <children>
                          <GridPane prefHeight="145.0" prefWidth="294.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <columnConstraints>
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            </columnConstraints>
                            <rowConstraints>
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            </rowConstraints>
                             <children>
                                <Label text="Base price:">
                                   <font>
                                      <Font size="20.0" />
                                   </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label text="Current Price:" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                   <font>
                                      <Font size="20.0" />
                                   </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label text="Bidder Name:" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                   <font>
                                      <Font size="20.0" />
                                   </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="baseprice" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                                   <font>
                                      <Font size="20.0" />
                                   </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="currentprice" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                                   <font>
                                      <Font size="20.0" />
                                   </font>
                                </Label>
                                <Label fx:id="biddername" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                   <font>
                                      <Font size="20.0" />
                                   </font>
                                </Label>
                             </children>
                          </GridPane>
                       </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                </items>
              </SplitPane>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
           <children>
              <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Item Name:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="20.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label fx:id="itemname" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Label">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="20.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label fx:id="description" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="56.0" prefHeight="176.0" prefWidth="233.0" text="Label" />
              <ButtonBar layoutX="81.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                <buttons>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Return" />
                    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bid" />
                </buttons>
              </ButtonBar>
           </children></AnchorPane>
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thanks in advance for the help :D

**Edit:** Inserted the packages as asked

Comment: The FXMLLoader, by default, creates instances of the controller class by calling the no-argument constructor: your `ItemViewController` class has no no-argument constructor.

Comment: So how can I change the code so that I receive the item clicked by the user and view its details?

Comment: Just create a set method for it, and call it when you get the reference to the controller.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks :D